# Oracle Apex : How to translate the message : Your session has expired?

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm running an Oracle Apex App and I'm trying to translate it.

Is is possible to translate the message : "Your session has expired"

I've been looking in the Translation Messages Documentation but with no success : https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/translating-messages.htm#HTMDB14004

Does anyone know how to translate that please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this reference help? https://community.oracle.com/thread/4157129

Comment: @Scott It does !! Thanks a lot !